# Is there a plugin to save/load button states?

Tags: sketch-app, symbols, plugin, button

I have many override settings in my button symbol. I want to customize button with these settings and save the state to use after. I am pretty shore I saw this kind of plugin some time ago but I can't find it know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the plugin again. Huh.

https://sketchpacks.com/ahmedmigo/Symbol-state